# Class 'HTML' not found

Tags: templating, laravel-5

I have required and installed "illuminate/html": "~5.0" like here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade and added it to the 'providers' and 'aliases' like there.

The problem is, I still get:

```
FatalErrorException in 65ad332c3ff984a4112203ba0538718c line 23:
Class 'HTML' not found
```

I have also tried to `use Html;` in the controller that 'makes' the view and in the view itself, but it did not help. Must I `use` the facade somewhere, or what could it be, that I am doing wrong?

I need this to use Html macros.

**edit:**
Seems to work now. I had to use `Html` in the view instead of `HTML`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The 5.0 docs are slightly misleading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0). If you are upgrading from a Laravel 4 app - you would be used to using `HTML` as the class.

So docs say to put this as your facade

```
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

but if you want to continue to use `HTML` then it should be this

```
'HTML'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```